# Can I use regex to reroute external URLs to a specific Angular Route?

Tags: regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my first attempt to figure this out I asked about setting up multiple static URLs for one $state in the [following question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959956/can-ui-router-handle-multiple-parameters-in-angularjs).  After finding out that aliasing isnt possible with Angular, I quickly realized this would be a problem without a base to the URL as everything passed in the URL becomes a parameter and screws up the app.

So in order to solve this from another angle I figured I could reroute the incoming URL to its proper Angular counter part using regex and sting matching.  The only issue with this is that I have no idea if Angular can do this and I'm terrible with regex...

So taking into account me original post and set up I have a current route that is set up like so.

```
 .state('ball', {
    parent: 'ballLayout',
    url: '/ball/{urlName}',
    views: {
      'cube.head': {
        templateUrl: 'partials/views/ball.head.html',
        controller: 'BallCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

The outside Rails application can have up to 4 different URL structures which all route to the same title like so

ball/title-of-page

bat/title-of-page

basket/title-of-page

beast/title-of-page

What I'd like to do is have my Angular app match up the ball, bat, basket, or beast and always route it back **to ball/title-of-page**.

So if someone sends out a link from the Rails side that is **beast/title-of-page** angular will see it and map it to **to ball/title-of-page**.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, solution could be like this *(check the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T6IbN6FaLNCPA0PdDERW?p=preview))*:

We will use the

- [`rule()`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#rule-for-custom-url-handling) for custom url handling

and here is the snippet:

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {

    var path = $location.path(),
        searchFor = /(ball|bat|basket|beast)/i, // the regex
        replaceWith = 'ball';

   var wasFound  = path.search(searchFor) > -1; // is there a match?

   return wasFound
   ? path.replace(searchFor, replaceWith)  // replace first occurance
   : path;

});
```

And now, all the url like:

```
  <li><a href="#/BALL/title-of-page-ball">ball</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/bat/title-of-page-bat">bat</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/basket/title-of-page-basket">basket</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/beast/title-of-page-beast">beast</a></li>
```

will be converted into:

```
href="#/ball/...."
```

the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T6IbN6FaLNCPA0PdDERW?p=preview)...

Comment: It appears to be doing the replace and sending the user to the correct URL however the entire app goes white screen with no data and no console info as to why.  I'm wondering if it has anything to do with my set up and current config getting in the way.  The full set up of my config section is as such [in this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7jf4bYbb7UK3hlN8mTzZ).

Comment: As I've shown in plunker, the rerouting is possible. Your specific (html5 style) solution is hard to reproduce, but at the end, it could most likely be achieved as well. In case of ui-router, the key is `rule()` ... if you can update your plunker to working version (for ball only) ... I can check, but currently it is just a copy/paste bin ...

Comment: That makes sense.  I tried to remove our html5 URL structure and then went with just the normal #bang solution, but it still failed.  There is probably something else going on here that I need to trouble shoot.  Not having any errors is really a problem however.  I'll create a working plunker today.  Thanks!

Comment: Great, if I will know how to, I will gladly assist. The `ui-router` is really exceptional tool! And it would be shame if you won't get what you can from that ;)

Comment: As a side note:  Does it matter that you are using Angular 1.3 beta if I'm still on 1.2?  I'm assuming there were no major changes to core and since Im using ui-router it doesnt matter.

Comment: In this case, we are talking about features of the `ui-router`, and that means, no difference (at the moment). but you can use 1.2.16 as well...

Comment: Ok I figured it out.  I'm not sure why, but for some reason Angular wasnt liking the fact that I was using ternary operators.  When I switched it to the following it worked fine.  Very odd.  Great answer!   

`$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {

      var path = $location.path(),
        searchFor = /(ball|beast|bat)/i, 
        replaceWith = 'ball';
      var wasFound = path.search(searchFor) > -1; 
        if (wasFound === true) {
          path = path.replace(searchFor, replaceWith);
          return path;
        }

    });`